# Data Types in Accelerate.framework

Tags: c++, lapack

I'm working on a program that uses the Accelerate framework (for LAPACK) and I have several issues.  The code is written in C but needs to include C++ headers.  I renamed the file to .cpp but it caused two errors, shown below.

[image: C++ Error Image]

So I then realized tried to `#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>` to include the headers, since what our LAPACK coder did was retype the definitions (`dgemm_(), dposv_(), etc.`) at the beginning of the file and rely on the compiler/linker to work things out.  So I commented out those and just did the #include.  What came out was this:

[image: Accelerate Error Image]

So, how do I use the LAPACK functions using Accelerate in a C++ file?  I'm not that familiar with LAPACK, so I'm not sure how that framework normally works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use call `dgemm_` and `dposv_` using the type `__CLPK_integer` or `long` instead of `int`. The error is because a `long*` cannot be implicitly converted to an `int*` in C++.

```
typedef long int    __CLPK_integer;
typedef long int    __CLPK_logical;
typedef float       __CLPK_real;
typedef double      __CLPK_doublereal;
typedef __CLPK_logical  (*__CLPK_L_fp)();
typedef long int    __CLPK_ftnlen;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.  Now I just have this error:  `error: 'dgemm_' was not declared in this scope`.  Interesting that it's fine with dposv_ which is called a few lines earlier in the same block of code.

Comment: @jfm: Probably because there's no `dgemm_` in clapack.  There is `cblas_dgemm` though.

Comment: That helps, but now: http://cl.ly/2Rc9/  EDIT: why can't you use Markdown in the comment fields?  :\

Comment: Actually, I think I've figured out a way to do the #include files in a way that will avoid issues and allow me to just use a C file for the LAPACK code; that way we won't have to deal with subtle differences in two versions of LAPACK, which it seems is what's causing this.  Unless there's a way to somehow use the same code for both C and C++ versions of LAPACK...

Comment: @jfm: `cblas_dgemm` has an entirely different prototype than `dgemm_`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.  :D  I think we'll just end up using the workaround for the #include files.  It seems to be working now, it's just a bit more awkward than I'd like (splitting some stuff into 2 files when it should be in 1) but I #included the second one in the first and it simplifies things for the rest of the #include statements.  Thanks for your help, though.  If we ever do decide to port things over those typedefs will help a lot.